# Python serial read buffer

Tags: python, serial-port, buffer, uart, nmea

I am trying to make a serial read buffer instead of using readlines() due to performance, but i am unable to make i work as intended.
I had some inspiration from the following [blog post](http://doschman.blogspot.dk/2013/01/parsing-nmea-sentences-from-gps-with.html).

My readBuffer class definition looks like this:

```
def readBuffer(self):
    try:
        data = self.gpsdevice.read(1)
        n = self.gpsdevice.inWaiting()
        if n:
            data = data + self.gpsdevice.read(n)
        return data
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        sys.exit(1)
```

I am reading NMEA data through uart and i need it to output line by line but when i execute the following test the output is not as intended

```
def test1():
    newdata = ""
    line = ""
    while uart1.isOpen():
        if newdata: 
            line = newdata
            newdata = ""
        line = line + uart1.readBuffer()    
        if "\r\n" in line:
            print line
            line = ""

test1()
```

Output:

```
$GNDTM,W84,,0.0000,N,0.0000,E,0.0000,W84*41
$GNGNS,,,,,,NN,00,,,,,,C*3C
$GNGBS,,,,,,,,,1,1*5F
$GNGBS,
,,,,,,,,2,1*5C
$GNRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N,C*22
$GNVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*32
$GNZDA,,,,,00,00*56

$GNDTM,W84,,0.0000,N,0.0000,E,0.0000,W84*41
$GNGNS,,,,,,NN,00,,,,,,C*3C
$GNGBS,,,,,,,,,1,1*5F
$GNGBS,
,,,,,,,,2,1*5C
$GNRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N,C*22
$GNVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*32
$GNZDA,,,,,00,00*56

$GNDTM,W84,,0.0000,N,0.0000,E,0.0000,W84*41
$GNGNS,,,,,,NN,00,,,,,,C*3C
$GNGBS,,,,,,,,,1,1*5F
$GNGBS,
,,,,,,,,2,1*5C
$GNRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N,C*22
$GNVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*32
$GNZDA,,,,,00,00*56

$GNDTM,W84,,0.0000,N,0.0000,E,0.0000,W84*41
$GNGNS,,,,,,NN,00,,,,,,C*3C
$GNGBS,,,,,,,,,1,1*5F
$GNGBS,
,,,,,,,,2,1*5C
$GNRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N,C*22
$GNVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*32
$GNZDA,,,,,00,00*56
```

Im looking to have sentencetype ($GN...) at the beginning of each line because i need to be able to split the line into a list. This is because i need to time the occurrences between each sentence type.

I made the whole thing work with readline() but since I'm going to pass many lines and i need the timing to be right i think it is better to use read().

What am i doing wrong here?